# BB10 signing migration

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Since the EOL date for deprecated BlackBerry services has arrived, what options are available to those of us who wish to continue programming for BB10?

Is it possible to get keys from your upgraded servers by changing a setting on our end?

Developing software for BB10 is still a fun, educational, unique experience. Our QNX version is able to run updated software, so obtaining debug tokens and signing keys is the only challenge.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry Signing Authority was decommissioned along with the rest of the BlackBerry 10 and BlackBerry OS infrastructure. It is no longer possible to generate debug tokens or sign BlackBerry 10 or BlackBerry OS applications.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance you have always offered to BB10, even through the period of inactivity. I hope a way can be found to install native apps, as can be done for Android apks. Would you be able to archive the developer docs on your github? Good luck in your future endeavours.

Comment: Thanks!  It's been fun helping all of the BBOS and BB10 developers over the years. :)

Comment: @MSohm may I ask you what is "exfat driver" for BB10 and how does it installs? This is literally the only thing I forgot to backup before infrastructure is closed. My naive assumption is that BAR file is silently installed when sdcard is inserted (like on android), but I also have a feeling that it is much more complicated than that. Thanks for your help throughout the years!

Comment: The exfat driver applies when using micro SD cards 64 GB and higher in a BB10 device. It allowed you to access the SD card over USB from a PC while it was installed in the device.

Comment: @MSohm when relatively high-capacity sdcard is inserted into BB10 phone, it tries to download "exfat driver". After some investigation, it seems that the driver is `/base/lib/dll/fs-exfat.so`.  In it, there is a string `This module is loaded by the "io-blk" module (from a "devb-*" driver).` So my question narrows down to "can it be loaded without root access?"

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible.  It looks like that driver is used by the device itself to read the SD card then, so ignore my point about "over USB" above. A workaround would be to use an SD card that is lower than 64 GB.

Comment: @Osyotr search Internet for sys.data.exfat.10.3.1.224.bar.  You'll find the driver.  If not, write me privately.  Good luck!